# Class not passed to ClassFileTransformer

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I have been developing a java agent for monitoring our web applications. I am adding agent to the JVM using -javaagent argument. During testing I found certain classes are not passed to the ClassFileTransformer, where as its Inner Classes are passed to the implementation.

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, 
                        String className, 
                        Class<?> classBeingRedefined, 
                        ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                        byte[] classfileBuffer) {

        logger.info("Loaded class: " + className);
        return null;
    }
```

For debugging have added the above implementation. When loading the class A whose implementation is

```
package x.y.z;
abstract class A {
    static enum Aa {
        ...
    }

    static enum Ab {
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

The debug log prints are

> Loaded class: x.y.z.A$Aa 
> Loaded class: x.y.z.A$Ab

I am unable to find any reasons, why there is no print for class x.y.z.A. Can anyone help me understand the issue?

Comment: I cannot analyse those incoherent code snippets. I see a `transform` method and a potential target class, but where is the agent implementation and the class around `transform`? I cannot see how and where the transformer is initialised. Obviously your problem is in the code you didn't show. It could even be in your `...` sections. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and ask questions in that style. You help others and ultimately yourself because you get answers consisting of more than speculation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show us how `A` is loaded. Or where you expect it to be loaded.

Comment: Run your VM with verbose class loading (`-verbose:class`) to see when it is loaded. Maybe only after your transformer is attached? Maybe not at all?